# How to check collision in collection (each element with each other)

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, collision

I have defined DispatcherTimer (Ticks 1 per ms). Also i have collection of Rectangle 's and method to check collision.

```
public List<Rectangle> Cars { get; set; }
int time = 0;

_timer = new DispatcherTimer();
_timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
_timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
_timer.Start();

void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Rectangle r in Cars)
    {
        r.Move()
    }
}

public bool CheckCollision(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
    bool result = false;
    Rect rect1 = new Rect((double)r1.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty),(double)r1.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty), r1.Width, r1.Height);
    Rect rect2 = new Rect((double)r2.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty), (double)r2.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty), r2.Width, r2.Height);

    if (rect1.IntersectsWith(rect2))
    {
        result = true;
    }
    else
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Question is how to (in tick) check with collision method (or any other way) that each object in colection interact with each other and for example stop that object from moving (while is collised).
Any idea or code would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
        foreach(Rectangle r in Cars.Where(c1 => Cars.All(c2 => !CheckCollision(c1,c2))))
            r.Move();
```